# Printing Wrong Data

Tags: c

So I'm trying to simulate a cache. Right now, I created structs for the blocks and the sets and created their constructors. When the constructor for cache set are activated it initilize all of the tags and valid bits to 0. However, I keep getting garbage data printed out for the tags.I'm probably set up my pointer incorrectly, but I having problems figuring out what.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
uint64_t tag;
unsigned int valid_bit;
}block;

typedef struct
{
unsigned int set_bit;
unsigned int number_of_blocks;
block * blocks;
}cache_set;


block *make_A_BLOCK(uint64_t tg, unsigned int v_b)
{
block *b = malloc(sizeof(block));
b->tag = tg;
b->valid_bit = v_b;
return b;
}
void change_tag(block *b,uint64_t t_g){b->tag = t_g;}
void change_bit(block *b,unsigned int v_b){b->valid_bit = v_b;}
uint64_t return_tag(block *b){ return b->tag;}
unsigned int return_bit(block *b){ return b->valid_bit;}


cache_set *make_A_CACHE_SET(unsigned int s_b, unsigned int n_b)
{
int i;
//uint64_t blank = 0;
cache_set *c_s = malloc(sizeof(cache_set));
c_s->set_bit = s_b;
c_s->number_of_blocks = n_b;
block *blocks = malloc(n_b * sizeof(block));


for (i=0; i < n_b; i++)
{
    blocks[i].tag = 0;
    blocks[i].valid_bit = 0;
}
free(blocks);
return c_s;
}
void print_cache_set(cache_set *c_s)
{
int i;
printf("Number of Cache Sets: %d \r\n",c_s->number_of_blocks);
for (i= 0; i < c_s->number_of_blocks ; i++)
{
    printf("Block %d ",i);
    printf(" Block Tag " "%" PRIu64, return_tag(&(c_s->blocks[i])));
    //printf(" Block Bit %d \r\n", blocks[i].valid_bit);
}
}


int main(void)
{
cache_set *test = make_A_CACHE_SET(0,10);
print_cache_set(test);
printf("done");
return 0;
}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh2zv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making a cash_set, you allocate blocks and assign the pointer to them to a local variable, and then you initialize the blocks one after the other.

But then, instead of letting the `c_s->blocks` point to this initialized list of blocks, you deallocate them with `free(blocks)`.

So I'd suggest to replace `free(blocks)` by `c_s->blocks = blocks`

Comment: Yeap this did it! Thank you so very much!